# Open URL by click on navigation drawer item

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My main java code :

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
   
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
 
import com.shrikanthravi.customnavigationdrawer2.data.MenuItem;
import com.shrikanthravi.customnavigationdrawer2.widget.SNavigationDrawer;
    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    SNavigationDrawer sNavigationDrawer;
    Class fragmentClass;
    public static Fragment fragment;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
        sNavigationDrawer = findViewById(R.id.navigationDrawer);
  
        // Menu add
   
        List<MenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();
 
        menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Home",R.drawable.ic_home));
        menuItems.add(new MenuItem("About us",R.drawable.ic_about));
        menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Subscribe Us",R.drawable.ic_subscribe));
        menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Follow Us",R.drawable.ic_follow));
        menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Rate Us",R.drawable.ic_rate));
  
        sNavigationDrawer.setMenuItemList(menuItems);
 
        fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
   
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment)fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        
        if (fragment!= null)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

   
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out).replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment).commit();
    
        }
    
    
        sNavigationDrawer.setDrawerListener(new  NavigationDrawer.DrawerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpening() {
    
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosing() {
    
                try {
                    fragment = (Fragment)fragmentClass.newInstance();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
    
                if (fragment!= null)
                {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out).replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment).commit();
    
                }
    
    
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened() {
    
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed() {
    
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
    
            }
    
        });
    }
}
```

My homefragment code :

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
    
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment
{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
       return  view;
    }
}
```

This code uses fragments.
I want to open an URL (example [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) from click on navigation drawer item.
Please help, I am new on this android development.

When a navigation item is clicked, I do not want this fragment page to open, instead I want to open an URL.

Comment: Try adding the following inside onDrawerClosing()

`Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);`

Comment: but its all for item in but i want only one item click to open url

Comment: Add an if clause,
Check whether the clicked item is what you want,
then add the code inside that if block

Comment: example my item is home then what is code plzz tell me brother i don't know how to write this code so plzz tell me

Comment: I posted it as an answer.
Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your listener:

```
if(fragment instanceof HomeFragment)
{
   Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
   Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")); startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

EDIT::

I found the library code that you're using.
It has a onClickListener.
Try this :

```
 sNavigationDrawer.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SNavigationDrawer.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuItemClicked(int position) {
                if(position==0){
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: brother plzz tell me where this code write in above my code i don't know about this becoz i m new in this field

Comment: menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Home",R.drawable.ic_home));
        menuItems.add(new MenuItem("About us",R.drawable.ic_about));
        menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Subscribe Us",R.drawable.ic_subscribe));
        menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Follow Us",R.drawable.ic_follow));
        menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Rate Us",R.drawable.ic_rate));
i want i click on second menu about us then open url so what is code

Comment: your code is add in my code but click on all items then open google but i want only one item to open google

Comment: Add it  before: `if (fragment!= null)`

Comment: brother same i write code before it but click on all item then same open google

Comment: brother any idea about it